# Graphical User Interfaces for cracks, keygens, etc

Tags: python, user-interface, interface

Have you ever used those cracks and keygens with the really nice interfaces and 8-bit music playing in the bg with special effects when you clicked buttons and stuff? I'd like to create works like such (the GUI part), but I'm wondering which GUI toolkit has that kind of flexibility.

Do all GUI toolkits have the ability to create such out-of-the-box (literally) designs? I even remember one famous cracker had a dancing panda or some animal at the top of his program that was really trippy. I bet that wasn't easy.

I was planning on trying to get started with Python and PyGTK, if it's even possible, I guess I'll find out.

Comment: I'm almost sure they do it with some very low level hacking, but it's only speculation :)

Comment: Usually those programs are not using any GUI toolkit - actually, many of them are not only using no special GUI toolkit but are also written in pure ASM.

Comment: I know that [easygui](http://www.ferg.org/easygui/epydoc/index.html) lets you put images on the GUI canvas. But I can't be sure off the top of my head, what kind of images it allows, etc. Also, it doesn't let you change the cursor type, etc

Comment: Clearly, you must be using keygens purely for user interface research purposes, right? :)

Comment: Crack the crack!And you will know how to make it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd wager most of those cracks are written in C or even assembly language, using the Windows API at a very low level. Very few, if any, are written in Python, and positively none are written using GTK. :) Crackers have different aesthetics than ordinary programmers, and they tend to idealize low-level programs with small executable size. They also usually know Assembly, C and low-level Windows API much better than they're familiar with cross platform toolkits such as GTK and Qt.

That being said, most modern toolkits can do at least some of what you describe. Playing sound when a button is clicked, for instance, is quite easy: all you have to do is to hook the to the button events and play a sound using your toolkit's sound API (or an additional library if your toolkit doesn't have sound capabilities). The same goes for music. Drawing graphics on your window's background is also possible with most toolkits I know, and although I have no experience with GTK, I guess it can do that as well.

Some of the things that might be harder to implement (depending on your toolkit) are non-rectangular windows (e.g. an egg-shaped window), and smooth animations that require at least some sort of double-buffering (if not hardware graphic acceleration support).